# document.getElementById.innerHTML not working for ejs-javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm currently working on our lab homepage using Express.js and ejs with javascript in Windows 10. Web browser is Google Chrome, and IDE is Web Storm.
But there is some errors around. 
Now I'm trying to display the content which is 2 columns of image, but It does not come up to the page. 
I suspect that there is issue about document.getElementById.innerHTML with my code. 
I look up all the answers here, but there is no exact answer I want. 

I tried everything including moving "script" section to the last of "body".
The reason I suspect document.getElementById.innerHTML is
**First** It works perfectly when I insert some part of img src to ejs file 
**Second** When I inspect developer console in google chrome, there isn't part I expected (div and img src part) 
**Third** In IDE console, there is no error for JavaScript file that have function for injecting html code to ejs. 
I really want to know why this is happening. I'm trying to figure out for several days.

p.s. Because I'm not an English speaker, there may be some ambiguity in expression. Please let me know.

here is my code 
**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host:'bisltest.kaist.ac.kr',
  port:3306,
  user:'root',
  password:'bisl2016bsrc1',
  database:'BISL_homepage'
});
connection.connect(function(err){
  if (err){
    console.error('mysql connection error');
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
.
.
//some stuff
.
.
router.get('/album',function(req,res,next) {

  var query = connection.query("select image_link from album", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.render('album.ejs', {
      title: 'Express',
      results:result
    });
  });
})
```

**album.ejs**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- === BEGIN HEADER ===-->
    <!--if IE 8html.ie8(lang='en')
    -->
    <!--if IE 9html.ie9(lang='en')
    -->
    <!-- [if !IE] <!-->
    <html lang="en">
      <!-- <![endif]-->
      <head>

        <title>Habitat - A Professional Bootstrap Template</title>


        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content=""/>
        <meta name="author" content=""/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>

        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/animate.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/font-awesome.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/nexus.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/responsive.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/custom.css"/>

        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="body-bg">

          <div id="header">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">

                <div class="logo"><a href="home" title=""><img src="images/BISL_logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a></div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="hornav" class="bottom-border-shadow">
            <div class="container no-padding border-bottom">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 no-padding">
                  <div class="visible-lg">
                    <ul id="hornavmenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li><a href="home" class="fa-home active">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="Professor" class="fa-user">Professor</a></li>
                      <li><a href="Research" class="fa-copy">Research</a></li>
                      <li><a href="Publication" class="fa-copy">Publication</a></li>
                      <li><a href="Patent" class="fa-copy">Patent</a></li>
                      <li><a href="Member" class="fa-users">Member</a></li>
                      <li><a href="album" class="fa-camera">Album</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="container background-white">
            <div class="row margin-vert-30">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>BISL Album</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div id="album" class="col-md-12 portfolio-group no-padding">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
.
.
//some stuff
.
.
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/ejs_edit.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var s = JSON.stringify(results)
      loop_for_ejs(s)
    </script>
```

**ejs_edit.js**

```
function loop_for_ejs(S){
    for(var v in S){
        var line =  "";
        line +='<'+'div class=\"col-md-6 portfolio-item margin-bottom-40 filer-code\">'+ '<div><a href=\"'+S[v].image_link+'\">'+'<figure><img src=\"'+S[v].image_link+'\">'+ '</figure>'+ '</a>'+ '</div>'+ '</div>';
        document.getElementById('album').innerHTML+=line;
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you check if javascripts/ejs_edit.js is offered from the server at all with that path?

Comment: No. I haven't think about that. How can I check that part?

Comment: open your site in the browser. Then you're e.g. at https://localhost:3000
append javascripts/ejs_edit.js - in this example https://localhost:3000/javascripts/ejs_edit.js Then you get either an error or you see the JS file

Comment: or another way to test it: simply copy paste the content of ejs_edit.js into your script tag in album.ejs

Comment: Thank you for your sincere comment. I've just tried that way, and the browser show me the that javascript file.

Comment: Is there an error or any output in the browser console?
Also you can edit your question with how the page looks like after rendering. For doing that right click somewhere on your page "inspect" (when using Chrome) then right click on the <html> tag and click copy - now you should have you're rendered page in the clipboard in order to share it with us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not telling ejs to render `results` into the html, at least not in the code you've posted. In your `album.ejs` file, change:

```
var s = JSON.stringify(results);
loop_for_ejs(s);
```

To:

```
var s = <%- JSON.stringify(results) %>;
loop_for_ejs(s);
```

**Or:**

Alternatively, if you are already doing this in some other section that you haven't posted, you shouldn't call `JSON.stringify` on `results` before calling `loop_for_ejs`, since you would then be iterating over the characters of a string, not an array of rows (and therefore `S[v].image_link` will always evaluate to `undefined`). Try this instead then:

```
loop_for_ejs(results);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've missed that part you've pointed out. I've done that modification also, but nothing happened. Sorry about that.

Comment: Which one of the two? Where are you rendering results in your code?

Comment: I've done both of them. I'm rendering the results in loop_for_ejs function in  'ejs_edit.js' using document.getElementById('album').innerHTML function. What I'm trying to do in that function is to inject some html phrase into 'album.ejs' to make 2 columns of pictures. In my expectation, that JS should put some html code to render the result. But , as I said, it didn't work. Am I missing something? I really want to know......

Comment: Yes, that part is clear. Add some logs to your code. Right before calling `loop_for_ejs(s);` add `console.log(s);`. What is the output? Also, on the server side. Is `results` empty?

Comment: Also, with rendering i didn't mean the client side rendering i meant ejs.

Comment: Oh my god..... results are not empty. and It works. It's like a magic! as soon as I put console.log into my ejs, It's magically worked. I don't know why It happened, but It works. I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Hm. Sure it had nothing to do with the cache? Anyway, sure, glad to help.